# NGINX redirect everything except one directory and its subdirectories

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, webserver

How do I need to modify the code that everything redirects to another website except the directory "l"? Also, all like e.g. /l/test shouldn't redirect.

```
location / {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

location ~ /l {
    root /var/www;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?l=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: How are you going to process your PHP code? You need some location that will pass requests for php-files either to some HTTP-listening backend or to fastcgi daemon. Otherwise you'll just get a raw php content of `index.php` with nginx response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that configuration its works!

```
root /var/www/;

location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location /l/ {
        rewrite ^/l/(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #...
    }
```